# Validating Oracle Table Data with Mongo DB Collection

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, oracle11g, data-migration

There is a problem as follows:

Data is migrated from Oracle to MongoDB

Two exact tables / collection
-One Table from Oracle R12
-One Table  in MongoDB.

I need to validate the number of records present in Oracle with the ones in MongoDB.

The Algorithm trying so far...

-Looping records in Oracle Table from 0..n

-Capture the primary key ID from Oracle Row

-Finding the corresponding record in MongoDB with that ID

-Validating the columns for that given row and testing the migrated data present in MongoDB.

Now the problem arises because of the enormous amount of records present in Oracle (More than a few million) to be validated with the migrated data in MongoDB

Thus each time there is a select fired upon oracle in this distributed environment will take a lag of 0.025s.

Anyone has a better approach for solving this. Kindly educate me :)

Thanking in advance